# SSL Handshake fails after clienthello

Tags: networking, openssl

EDIT: I'll leave this as a good example of debugging SSL.

Final analysis: We had a networking issue in which one of our routers was misconfigured for a totally different application causing that router to be running borderline on CPU usage. The first few handshakes didn't pin it... then a subsequent one did and the connection was dropped as the router became overloaded. This presented as an SSL problem when it was really something else entirely.

Take-away: When SSL drops completely in mid connection make sure to check load level of routers in your control as well.

---

I've been at this for a while so hopefully I can provide an accurate picture.

We have SVN and Git repositories at a third party provider. We noticed that each would hang intermittently with no error given to the screen. In SVN's case the process had to be kill -9ed in Git a ctrl-C would suffice.

Looking into I found that the SSL handshake negotiation was failing. In SVN we would get to the handshake part and ... nothing.

Now, I know we use these repos elsewhere without known issues, so that is the first rabbithole I go down.

1. This only happens on one datacenter. Not in our whoel network. These repos are fine everywhere, else, but at this one datacenter about 1 in 3ish requests hangs on the SSL handshake.
2. These same machines can access SSL handshakes without issue everywhere else except this third party provider.

So, I delved into the SSL handshake, and finally landed at:

openssl s_client -msg -debug -state -connect DOMAIN.DOM:443 which stops here:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
write to 0x20b94e0 [0x20b9560] (317 bytes => 317 (0x13D))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 38 01 00 01-34 03 03 88 0a 00 73 97   ....8...4.....s.
0010 - 12 69 c9 00 65 29 10 f6-57 00 57 44 e8 0e 3f cf   .i..e)..W.WD..?.
0020 - af a0 f9 80 e2 20 98 f0-d2 79 8c 00 00 9e c0 30   ..... ...y.....0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a c0 22 c0 21 00 a3   .,.(.$.....".!..
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 39-00 38 00 88 00 87 c0 32   ...k.j.9.8.....2
0050 - c0 2e c0 2a c0 26 c0 0f-c0 05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35   ...*.&.......=.5
0060 - 00 84 c0 12 c0 08 c0 1c-c0 1b 00 16 00 13 c0 0d   ................
0070 - c0 03 00 0a c0 2f c0 2b-c0 27 c0 23 c0 13 c0 09   ...../.+.'.#....
0080 - c0 1f c0 1e 00 a2 00 9e-00 67 00 40 00 33 00 32   .........g.@.3.2
0090 - 00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44-c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0 25   .....E.D.1.-.).%
00a0 - c0 0e c0 04 00 9c 00 3c-00 2f 00 96 00 41 c0 11   .......<./...A..
00b0 - c0 07 c0 0c c0 02 00 05-00 04 00 15 00 12 00 09   ................
00c0 - 00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06-00 03 00 ff 01 00 00 6d   ...............m
00d0 - 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02-00 0a 00 34 00 32 00 0e   ...........4.2..
00e0 - 00 0d 00 19 00 0b 00 0c-00 18 00 09 00 0a 00 16   ................
00f0 - 00 17 00 08 00 06 00 07-00 14 00 15 00 04 00 05   ................
0100 - 00 12 00 13 00 01 00 02-00 03 00 0f 00 10 00 11   ................
0110 - 00 23 00 00 00 0d 00 20-00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03   .#..... ........
0120 - 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01-04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02   ................
0130 - 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03-00 0f 00 01 01            .............
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0138], ClientHello
01 00 01 34 03 03 88 0a 00 73 97 12 69 c9 00 65
29 10 f6 57 00 57 44 e8 0e 3f cf af a0 f9 80 e2
20 98 f0 d2 79 8c 00 00 9e c0 30 c0 2c c0 28 c0
24 c0 14 c0 0a c0 22 c0 21 00 a3 00 9f 00 6b 00
6a 00 39 00 38 00 88 00 87 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a c0
26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d 00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 12 c0
08 c0 1c c0 1b 00 16 00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a c0
2f c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13 c0 09 c0 1f c0 1e 00
a2 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 33 00 32 00 9a 00 99 00
45 00 44 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29 c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00
9c 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0
02 00 05 00 04 00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14 00 11 00
08 00 06 00 03 00 ff 01 00 00 6d 00 0b 00 04 03
00 01 02 00 0a 00 34 00 32 00 0e 00 0d 00 19 00
0b 00 0c 00 18 00 09 00 0a 00 16 00 17 00 08 00
06 00 07 00 14 00 15 00 04 00 05 00 12 00 13 00
01 00 02 00 03 00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 23 00 00 00
0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05
03 04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02
02 02 03 00 0f 00 01 01
SSL_connect:unknown state
```

And it hangs there. On successful connections the next lines to that debug output *should be*

```
read from 0x1735590 [0x173ab70] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 42 02                                 ....B.
0007 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x1735590 [0x173ab7a] (64 bytes => 64 (0x40))
0000 - 00 3e 03 03 52 fd 41 af-09 0b 96 d6 c4 01 c2 1b   .>..R.A.........
0010 - eb e9 23 71 93 a6 1b 78-df 67 17 fe 86 c4 f9 82   ..#q...x.g......
0020 - 53 4f 36 09 00 c0 30 00-00 16 ff 01 00 01 00 00   SO6...0.........
0030 - 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00-23 00 00 00 0f 00 01 01   ........#.......
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0042], ServerHello

02 00 00 3e 03 03 52 fd 41 af 09 0b 96 d6 c4 01
c2 1b eb e9 23 71 93 a6 1b 78 df 67 17 fe 86 c4
f9 82 53 4f 36 09 00 c0 30 00 00 16 ff 01 00 01
00 00 0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 23 00 00 00 0f 00
01 01
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
```

So, as you can see this is way before the handshake is close to done.

From what I can tell, our clients initiate the handshake (cleinthello) and *sometimes* get silence on the wire.

I've already tried upgrading openssl, with no change. And again, this is only connecting to this one provider out of this one datacenter.

I'm down to some sort of networking issue filtering outgoing SSL traffic in some way, but I have no idea why that would be happening.

Any thoughts on where to go next in the troubleshooting process would be much appreciated. Thanks.

edit: Tried multiple ciphers and can reproduce with all, leading me again to possible network issue.

edit: Similar results with gnutls:

```
ifx14:/home/cadre/stresler# gnutls-cli -d 9 DOMAIN.DOM
Resolving 'DOMAIN.DOM'...
Connecting to 'X.X.X.X:443'...
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_DSS_ARCFOUR_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: DHE_PSK_SHA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_DSS_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_DSS_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_DSS_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: RSA_ARCFOUR_MD5
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Keeping ciphersuite: PSK_SHA_ARCFOUR_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_AES_128_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_AES_256_CBC_SHA1
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: Removing ciphersuite: SRP_SHA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA1
|<2>| EXT[0x1a11a60]: Sending extension CERT_TYPE
|<2>| EXT[0x1a11a60]: Sending extension SERVER_NAME
|<3>| HSK[0x1a11a60]: CLIENT HELLO was send [131 bytes]
|<4>| REC[0x1a11a60]: Sending Packet[0] Handshake(22) with length: 131
|<2>| ASSERT: gnutls_cipher.c:204
|<4>| REC[0x1a11a60]: Sent Packet[1] Handshake(22) with length: 136
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you're next step is to get the same views of the exchange at your third party provider. That will allow you to isolate the problem to the server or the network.

Comment: Is there an proxy or load balancer in play here? I know F5 had problems with a large `ClientHello`. The `ClientHello` was too large because of 80 or so cipher suites crammed into the initial packet, and F5 only provided a small fixed size buffer for the initial packet. The workarounds are (1) patch the load balancer, or (2) reduce your cipher suites. See [OpenSSL 1.0.1e CipherSuites and TLS1.2 more mixed signals than my xgf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497742/openssl-1-0-1e-ciphersuites-and-tls1-2-more-mixed-signals-than-my-xgf) for a brief discussion of the issue.

Comment: `openssl s_client -msg -debug -state -connect DOMAIN.DOM:443` - you might try adding `-tls1` option. TLSv1.2 (and TLSv1.1) had trouble a few years ago due to broken clients and servers. Ubuntu still disables the protocols for OpenSSL (cf., [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: OpenSSL downlevel version, and does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576)). If `-tls1` fixes the issue, then you are probably dealing with one of the broken servers (and more importantly, unpatched server).

Comment: Turns out it is our IP space. We are on 198.16.*.*. I believe that some firewall between them and us is blocking this too broadly, meaning to block the 198.18.0.0/15 and 198.51.100.0/24 reserved IP spaces.

Answer (score 4):

This is old and already answered, but we suffered the same exact issue and the cause was different.

The key was to sniff traffic on our edge router, where we saw ICMP messages to the server (GitHub.com) asking for *fragmentation*. This was messing the connection, with retransmissions, duplicated ACKs and so.

[image]

The ICMP packet had a field, `MTU of next hop` with a weird value, 1450. The usual value is 1500.

[image]

We checked our router and one of the interfaces (an Ethernet tunnel) had this value as MTU, so the router was taking the minumum MTU of all interfaces as next hop. As soon as we removed this interface (it was unused), the SSL handshake started to work again.

Comment: We have had similar issue with MTU set to 1496 on a firewall (for IPSec VPN) with MTU set on a node to 1500. Interesting part was that we have had problems with SSL handshake only to SOME HTTPS server (one, actually). Anyway setting MTU to 1496 on the node helped. So thanks a lot for this answer @charli!

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, the client hello has one byte to much on position 00cb: the 0xFF should not be there. So the following bytes data cannot be read correctly...

00c0 - 00 14 00 11 00 08 00 06-00 03 00 **ff** 01 00 00 6d   ...............m

Not sure, but it seems to be a bug in openssl, so a firewall or web proxy ignores the request.

Answer (score 1):

For folks who come across this issue, I created a checklist:

- Make sure all TLS versions are enabled in Internet Explorer (This is for testing. You can later disable the unsecure versions once you find out the root cause)
- Check the registry keys below to make sure what you set in Internet Explorer is applied at registry level. If there are working and non-working servers, mirror the working server’s settings `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols`
- Collect a network trace from the client side. Check if the client and server are agreeing on a cipher suite. If they are not, make sure the client uses the cipher suites the server is trying to use. The Group Policy setting is below `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > SSL> Configuration Settings > SSL Cipher Suite Order`
- If the issue sill exists, look for any network device (proxy, firewall, load balancer etc.) in between that might be blocking TLS traffic
- Check the website binding in IIS. Make sure the certificate is valid and the port is set to 443
- Make sure the port 443 is listened in the server (`netstat -an -p TCP | find /I "listening"`). More details: Port 80 and 443 are not listened in IIS server
  Change the port number to 444 and test website. If it is accessible, it means there is a software blocking or overwriting 443 port. [More details](https://port135.com/2019/11/07/port-80-and-443-are-not-listened-in-iis-server/)
- Disable Windows Firewall (If it works, you can enable it back and set up rules accordingly)
- Look for any third-party applications such as antivirus or endpoint protection software in the server such as Symantec Endpoint Security and Symantec Data Center Security Server Agent (Based on [this document](https://help.symantec.com/cs/DCS2.0/DCS2_0/v95014100_v110163010/About-using-firewalls-with-Data-Center-Security:-Server-Advanced?locale=EN_US), Security Server Agent uses port 443). Uninstall them (Don’t just disable. Uninstall completely. If it works, you can install them back and configure them accordingly)
- Check if there is any Microsoft software that is using port 443. Applications like SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) and Windows Admin Center might interfere the port 443. [An example](https://port135.com/2019/05/16/solved-503-service-unavailable-windows-admin-center/)

Source: [The missing Server Hello in TLS handshake (ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR](https://port135.com/2020/08/01/the-missing-server-hello-in-tls-handshake-err_ssl_protocol_error/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar problem. SSL handshake terminated with error right after ClientHello. It turned out the server required stronger ciphers than I had installed so I had to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).

More interestingly, we had the very same problem on a server and we had the jars for JCE there but some older version so it suffered the same problem. Replacing them with the newest version solved the issue.

BTW, do you know how to get required server ciphers? Or better compare the client and server ciphers? So one would immediately see the mismatch.