# TeamCity Git plugin fails with SSL handshake error

Tags: java, git, ssl, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

The Git plugin in TeamCity (v9.1.1) cannot connect to a Git repository over HTTPS. I get the following error:

> Failed to collect changes, error: List remote refs failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

I doubt that the problem is with the SSL certificate. It is signed by a DigiCert root CA and also exists in the java keystore in use. The Java strong cipher library mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273505 is also installed.

For full stacktrace see bugreport at 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42280

Comment: Just to double check, have you successfully cloned using the same URL from another machine?

Comment: Yes, it's a widely used corporate code server and the repository is in use on dev machines and a Jenkins build server @SteveChapman