# SSL handshake failure with node.js https

Tags: node.js, ssl, docker, wireshark, handshake

I have an API running with `express` using `https`. For testing, I've been using tinycert.org for the certificates, which work fine on my machine.

I'm using `docker` to package up the app, and `docker-machine` with `docker-compose` to run it on a digital ocean server.

When I try to connect with Chrome, I get `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`. When running this with `curl`, I get a handshake failure: `curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect`.

I tried to debug with Wireshark's SSL dissector, but it hasn't given me much more info: I can see the "Client Hello" and then the next frame is "Handshake Failure (40)".

I considered that maybe node on the docker container has no available ciphers, but it has a huge list, so it can't be that. I'm unsure as to what's going on and how to remedy it.

**EDIT**

Here's my `createServer()` block:

```
let app = express();
let httpsOpts = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync("./secure/key.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./secure/cert.pem")
};
let port = 8080;
https.createServer(httpsOpts, app).listen(port);
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you paste your https.createServer() line?

Comment: Incidentally, I tried running my entire setup in a VM on my laptop, and it works there too.

Comment: I wonder if it could be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767003/ssl-handshake-fails-after-clienthello

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I am experiencing the exact same thing, thanks

Comment: @JaredWilkin I'm afraid I did not. Not sure exactly what I did that fixed it in the end but I haven't seen this problem for a while. Sorry not to be of more use!

Comment: Has anyone figured this out by now? I get the same error with this one-liner in node v8.2.1: `require('https').createServer().listen(8097)`

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for a really long time too, there's a weird fix:

1. Don't convert your certs to .pem; it works fine as .crt and .key files.
2. Add `ca: fs.readFileSync("path to CA bundle file")` to the https options.
   It looks like your server is only sending the top certificate and the CA bundle file has the intermediate and root certificates which you'll need for non-browser use.
3. **IMPORTANT!** Reinstall or update node to the latest version.
   You can use `sudo apt-get upgrade` if you're on Linux (it may take a while).
4. Re-download your certificate or get a new one.

If you are acting as your own certificate authority it could be not recognizing / trusting the certificate, so try testing your site on [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

If you're using the http2 API try adding `allowHTTP1: true` to the options.